# Why is a html-form submission inside a modal not being picked up by submit function and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, mdbootstrap

**Question:** why is a form submission not being picked up by `$("#form_name").submit(function (event) {...});` and therefore ajax call not being executed?

---

**Possible Cause:** While it's not clear to me why this isn't working, I suspect it's related to an improper combination of MDBootstrap modal classes, jQuery Ajax, and html form.

---

**Details:**

To be able to edit rows in my data table, I use the following modal with an embedded form tag, see below. If the submit button is clicked, the datatable gets updated in the browser. But but my ajax call, which I need to send the edited fields back to my controller, is not being served (i.e. the console.log() function is not being executed).

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade modalEditClass" id="modalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="/zkl/edit_pers_post" method="post" id="editForm">
                <div class="modal-body mx-3 modal-inputs">
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <label>Nachname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nachname" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <label>Vorname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="vorname" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <label>Kürzel</label>
                    <input type="text" name="kuerzel" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <label>Telefon</label>
                    <input type="text" name="tel" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <label>E-Mail</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <label>ID</label>
                    <input type="number" name="id" readonly class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center editInsideWrapper">
                    <button id="button-save-edit" type="submit" name="submit"
                      class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block editInside" data-dismiss="modal">Edit
                      form
                      <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Submit function and AJAX call:

```
<script>
  $("#editForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serializeArray(); //Encode form elements for submission
    
    /* test log */
    console.log(form_data)

    $.ajax({
      url: post_url,
      contentType: "application/json",
      type: request_method,
      data: JSON.stringify(form_data)
    })
  });
</script>
```

my datatable is constructed as follows:

html

```
<div class=table-responsive-md>
   <table id="ex1" class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   </table>
</div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
  // construct DataTable using data variable and column titles
  $('#ex1').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: [
      ...
    ],
    // add some column definitions
    "columnDefs": [
      ...
    ]
  });

  // construct mdbEditor
  $('#ex1').mdbEditor({
    modalEditor: true,
  });
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
```

thank you for reading and if possible answering this question.

Comment: Your <form> is empty. You have a `</form>` in the same line. Proper indentation will help catch errors like that; as you can see the <div> in the next line isn't indented.

Comment: @ChrisG that is a careless mistake. very sorry for this. unfortunately removing it doesn't solve the stated issue.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/yksb5vup/

Comment: I see. But your fiddle is missing the first div element, which I need. <div class="modal fade modalEditClass" id="modalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: Makes absolutely zero difference, but would hide the form in the fiddle.

Comment: I managed to make it work now. But it still seems very strange to me. I had to remove data-dismiss='modal' and the editInside class from my button tag... even though in your fiddle it worked fine, in situ code something is definitely off. but glad it works now, thank you, I appreciate your help.